# How to get text from MySQL and set it on TextView

Tags: android, mysql, xml, android-volley, textview

I am making a like-book app. It'll have 600 pages. I don't want to make 600 activities.

How can I get text from MySQL db and set it on a text view using Volley?

I am using a list view.

Here's what I have so far.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class CantosHimnario extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cantos_himnario);

    populateListView();
}

private void populateListView() {

    String[] cantosHimnario = {"1. Abre Tu Oido",
            "2. A Cristo Quiero Servir"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.cantos_name, cantosHimnario);

    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewOne);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
}
```

An example would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrieve-data-from-mysql-database-in-android-using-volley/

I tried this and works for me

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it.